# Download file from url with no specified filename

Tags: r, curl, download

I would like to download a file from a url where the filename is not specified. If i type this url (https://www.cpr.dk/vejregister) into the browser it downloads the correct file.

If I write this code only the header is downloaded:

```
# In R
download.file(url = "https://www.cpr.dk/vejregister",
              destfile = "/data/kkgrunddata/Vejdata/vejdata_latest",
              method='curl')

# In BASH
>more vejdata_latest

<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="/media/21570/vejregister_hele_landet_pr_181201.zip">here</a>.</h2>
</body></html>
```

Do you have any suggestions of how to download the file without specifying the filename from the header?

Comment: My guess would be that some javascript (or some other language?) is accepting your click and then passing the file to download. If that's the case, you could use e.g. phantomjs to execute javascript on the webpage and get the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the issue with your code. Upon removing the `method='curl'` argument, I got it to download without specifying the link in the header.

```
download.file(url = "https://www.cpr.dk/vejregister",
          destfile = "./vejdata_latest")
```

Edit: If you're on Windows, don't forget the file extension (.zip in this case)

Comment: No. If you're on Windows, you need to add the extension (.zip). UNIX systems recognise the filetype automatically. My R session also recognises it:
`Content type 'application/x-zip-compressed'`. Good point though, will update answer.

Comment: Ahhh, then it makes sense. I just thought it was bytes or something :P